# Why are bugs responsible for big deficiencies in functionality given such low priority?

Tags: compiz, multiple-monitors, 3d, cube

Well, first of all, change is inevitable and mostly good. Furthermore attempts at simplifying the User Interface such as Gnome 3, Unity to make Linux more inclusive hold much promise, even though they adversely affect my style of working.

Additionally, though now retired, I have worked with computers for 47 years, and though I do nothing serious for others now, I still do heavy duty things.

10.04 LTS is my big workstation, and I had three 10.10 systems for Mythtv, and one of which is further adapted for video & related.  The Mythtv were 10.10 because of a dormant bug regarding installing to 10.04.

My work habits consistently use dual monitors, compiz cube and 3D windows with the computing horsepower to support them.

The dual monitors with separate X screens has been not been functional since 11.04, and cube/3D windows not functional in Unity, and with diminished functionality Gnome.

There is a bug filed ([after upgrade to 12.04 amd64 Gnome Classic not properly draw second screen](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1002641))

I have mitigated the situation some by switching to Xubuntu and eschewing Unity.

The question that comes to mind is why this bug is not given more attention in that it nearly cuts functionality in half for more competent workstations.

Sample Xubuntu 12.04 workspace...
[image]

Please know that I appreciate all the hard work and dedication required to pull off something as big as Ubuntu, *et al*.

Comment: Please refer to this question and answer which I wrote which uses information that is copied verbatim from the Bug Squad documentation on Bug Importance:  [How are Ubuntu Bugs' Importance Values Decided?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/153692/how-are-ubuntu-bugs-importance-values-decided)

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason for the priority set to low is for a few reasons.

1) You're talking about functionality that isn't part of the Core Ubuntu experience. Unity is fully supported by Canonical and is what they are pushing (see removing Kubuntu developer). Gnome Shell and Gnome Classic aren't something that they support at all, so that can contribute to the priority.

2) There aren't that many people affected by it. Looking at the "heat" of that bug you listed, it's 54, with puts you in the top 25% of bug heat against Compiz, but just barely. There are many more bugs with quite a bit more heat than that one. (The top bug has 1214 heat). There are only X amount of developers, and most of them aren't paid. Their resources are focused where they can do the most good.

3) It was initially marked low due to missing information, then never updated. Although had it been updated, I wouldn't put it higher than medium.

4) I don't use separate X screens myself, nor do I use compiz cube. I do have twinview setup with my two monitors and Unity and it works fine for me. I'd imagine that my setup is more common than yours, also contributing to the bug priority.

Comment: It seems that the Canonical posse is galloping off in pursuit of the elusive, fickle and capricious casual user at the expense of more competent and serious user ⋯ my problem is now abandoned I'll have to eschew Ubuntu and find another distro that supports my working style.  I generally prefer to work on my own stuff, not the tools (the computers) needed.  Multiple screens with easy‧to‧use multiple desktops make a lot possible for me, and compiz was a godsend. It would have been helpful to me if the deprecations and un‧abhorred bugs could have been mentioned in the release notes.